# Longest substring of 2 alternating characters

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve such competitive programming problem:

> Alex likes to laugh a lot. Laughter is a sequence of alternating letters "a" and "h". For example, "ahahaha", "hah" and "a" are laughter and "abacaba" and "hh" are not.
>   Alex speaks very quickly, so all his words merge into one big one. You need to find out how long he can laugh. You have a line - a recording of Alex's conversation. Determine the maximum length of laughter in this conversation.
>
> Input file is called "laugh.in"
>
> Output file is called "laugh.out"
>
> **Input data:**
>   The first line of the input file contains a single integer **N (1 < N ≤ 10^5)** - the length of the string with Alex's conversation. The second line contains a string of small Latin letters of length N - recording Alex's conversation.
>
> **Output data:**
>   Output one number - the longest laugh length in Alex's conversation

Here's some examples of how input/output data must look like.

> **Examples:**
>
> **Input in laugh.in**
>   
>   `5
>   ahaha`
>
> **Output in laugh.out**
>   
>   `5`
>
> **Input in laugh.in**
>   
>   `24
>   ahahrunawayahahsofasthah`
>
> **Output in laugh.out**
>   
>   `4`
>
> **Input in laugh.in**
>   
>   `10
>   ahahaahaha`
>
> **Output in laugh.out**
>   
>   `5`

So, here is my code, that is supposed to solve given problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("laugh.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("laugh.out", "w", stdout);

    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    int n, i;
    cin >> n;

    char *s = new char[n + 1];
    getchar();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        s[i] = getchar();
    }
    s[n] = '\0';

    int max_length = 0;
    int length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        length += !length && (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'h');
        if ((s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'h') ||
            (s[i] == 'h' && s[i + 1] == 'a'))
        {
            length += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            max_length = max(max_length, length);
            length = 0;
        }

    }

    cout << max(max_length, length) << endl;

    delete[] s;
    return 0;
}
```

It only passes 13 tests with other 33 resulting in "Wrong answer" verdict.
So why my code is not working? Please, give counter examples to it or explain error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have sample input/output for when it's failing?

Comment: @ChrisMM no, I do not and it is the main problem. I have tried many times with my own samples, but all the time the answer was correct

Comment: How does it process this string `"a"` ?

Comment: To clarify, `i` appears intended to index the visible characters, and not the terminating null character.  So the use of `s[i+1]` when examining visible characters is reaching the null.

Comment: Asking question in plain language with a nice example is always better than asking with a story. "s[i + 1]" inside the for loop is definitely a problem when i = n-1. you should use ++i or i++ other than i += 1.

Comment: Your program does no error checking of `n`.  It might be given as a negative, just to see if you check.

Comment: @Dimitry It outputs 1

Comment: @ManojBanik i += 1, ++i are equivalent

Comment: @donjuedo It is given in problem statement that 1 <= N <= 10000

Comment: @ManojBanik String contains "\0" at nth index so it is valid when i = n - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not write everything in `main` (learn to avoid it ASAP).

Secondly, the task doesn't say anything about opening files.

Avoid the use of `new` `delete` in modern C++; it is a bad practice to use it.

Here is pattern you can start over:

```cpp
size_t laugh_length(const std::string& s)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    size_t l;
    cin >> l;
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(l);
    cin >> s;
    cout << laugh_length(s) << '\n';
}
```

---

After an extra comment form OP I see another bit problem with OP code:

```cpp
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

and then use of:

```cpp
getchar();
```

which is `cstdio` API which synchronization has been disabled.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/PJzjc1joKQgmpbwa
vs https://wandbox.org/permlink/aH3OypI94CpgNuxd

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am familiar with C++ coding standards. But when I solve competitive programming problems I am trying to write mostly C-like code to reach best possible performance

Comment: My code is giving correct answer for string "oao". Your online code runner definitely has problems with character representation. Just try to output string, read from standard input

Comment: Oh man now with your comment is see additional problem with YOUR code.

Comment: Oh sorry! It is actually given in problem that input is read from "laught.in" and output is written to laugh.out file.

Comment: Thanks man! I just removed ios::sync_with_stdio call and now it works!

Comment: Could you explain more thoroughly why sync_with_stdio breaks my code?

Comment: @blackoutnet: I would guess that `cin >> n` is reading the newline (that terminates the integer) and then holding onto it. With `sync_with_stdio(true)` (the default), it puts that newline back where the C APIs will see it; but with `sync_with_stdio(false)`, it apparently doesn't. This means that when you try to read and discard the newline with `getchar()`, you're actually reading and discarding the first letter of the recording.

Comment: @blackoutnet proper fix is my starting pattern.

Comment: @ruakh with `sync_with_stdio(false)` this instruction `cin >> n` reads from stdin more data then expected, to the buffer as a result `getchar` reads beyond actual data (file).

Comment: @MarekR, Thank you very much for help!